# Prevent curve_fit from trying certain values

Tags: python, curve-fitting, ln

I'm trying to use Python's curve_fit to fit a function to some data.

I have a function

*y = aln(bx + 1)*

where a and b are constants to be found, y is the dependant variable and x is the dependant variable.

The data for x and y are given by `xdata` and `ydata` respectively.

So far I have the following code:

```
def func(x, a, b):
     return a * np.log(x * b + 1)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, maxfev = 5000)
```

However when running the code, I get the error:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log return a * np.log(x * b + 1)
```

Which I believe is due to the fact that curve_fit is trying negative values inside the log.

How can I prevent curve_fit from trying negative numbers and throwing up the error?  Is there another way to approach this?

Comment: Can you joint to the question a representative example of data (numeric not graph).

Comment: @JJacquelin I cannot share the full dataset for academic copyright reasons but will add a reduced version of the data

Answer (score 0):

if `curve_fit` iterates a single value each time just add a max() check:

```
 a * np.log(max(0,x * b + 1))
```

if it does it from a numpy array, you can change negative values with a boolean mask:

```
X = x * b + 1
boolean_mask = (x * b + 1)<0
X[boolean_mask] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks v much!  I had a go at doing this but unfortunately this lead to negative values of b sometimes being chosen!

Comment: @Hallonmallic : One cannot help if no numerical example is provided in order to peproduce and study a case where the difficulty occurs.